# Apply a Macro to range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need to apply the code below to a range of cells (i.e. B24:B28) - how do I edit to make this happen?

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String

On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$B$24" Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Target.Address = "$B$24"
```

This is the line you're interested in modifying.

If you only want it to occur on a single cell, you likely want to add above it

```
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

Now that we know it was only a single cell that was clicked, we can use intersect to keep the code short and replace the first line with

```
If Not Intersect(Target, [B24:B28]) is Nothing Then
```

Alternatively, we could just replace the single line with

```
If Target.Address = "$B$24" Or Target.Address = "$B$25" Or Target.Address = "$B$26" Or Target.Address = "$B$27" Or Target.Address = "$B$28"
```

But as you can see, that gets a bit less elegant pretty quickly.

My advice - replace:

```
If Target.Address = "$B$24"
```

With:

```
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, [B24:B28]) is Nothing Then
```

Final code becomes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String

On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, [B24:B28]) is Nothing Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        End If
    End If
End If
```

In the future, if you want to change the `Range` this affects, you can just modify the `[B24:B28]`